# Swift: change image multiple times

Tags: ios, swift, ios8

In my app I would like to display multiple images in one control and finally settling on the last image. The following code runs through fine but only the last image displays. It's like the page doesn't refresh after setting the image. Here is my code:

```
var num: UInt32 = 1
            let roll1: [UInt32] = [
                randRange(1,upper: 6),
                randRange(1,upper: 6),
                randRange(1,upper: 6),
                randRange(1,upper: 6),
                randRange(1,upper: 6),
                randRange(1,upper: 6),
                randRange(1,upper: 6),
                randRange(1,upper: 6)
            ]

for index in 0...7 {
                Dice1.hidden = true
                num = roll1[index]
                switch num
                {
                case 1:
                    Dice1.image = UIImage(named: "one.png")
                case 2:
                    Dice1.image = UIImage(named: "two")
                case 3:
                    Dice1.image = UIImage(named: "three")
                case 4:
                    Dice1.image = UIImage(named: "four")
                case 5:
                    Dice1.image = UIImage(named: "five")
                case 6:
                    Dice1.image = UIImage(named: "six")
                default:
                    Dice1.image = UIImage(named: "one.png")
                }
                Dice1.hidden = false
}
```

How do I get the images to all display?

Comment: After seeing that code, I think *Dice1* is an UIImageView? When you set Dice1.image you overwrite the image in the image view (if there is one). If you want more than one image to be displayed, I think you need more than one UIImageView.

Comment: I want 8 images to show in the same UIImageView one at a time, each showing for a half a second or so.Then the last image to remain on the page

Comment: I don't see any pausing code. You're most likely changing the image so quickly that it all happens within one frame.

Comment: That's what I think. How do you slow it down?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend using `NSTimer` for this one. It won't hold your main thread and would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

You can put this at the end of the code inside the for:

```
sleep(0.5);
```